# Printing pattern with two diffrent characters

Tags: c

I have task to do with recursion in C. I need to create function which takes one argument in declaration. The main  goal of this task is print on the screen the same numbers of "+" and "-" next to them.
Example:
n = 0 null
n= 1 „+-”
n = 2 „++--”
n = 3 „+++---”
n = 4 „++++----”
I create two functions like that :

```
   int pattern1(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
         printf("+");
         return pattern1(n-1);
    }
}
int pattern2(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
         printf("-");
         return pattern2(n-1);
    }
}
```

How to create one function to this task?
Additionally I want to create another function with "-" and "+" example:
n = 0 „-”
n = 1 „+-+”
n = 2 „++-++”
n =3 „+++-+++”
n = 4 „++++-++++”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void print_pattern1(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    printf("+");
    print_pattern1(--n);
    printf("-");
}

void print_pattern2(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        printf("-");
        return;
    }
    printf("+");
    print_pattern2(--n);
    printf("+");
}
```